# Flutter integration test for UI and HTTP call

Tags: flutter, integration-testing

I have a simple login screen that calls login API and I trying to wait for the second screen after ProgressIndicator finishes and the new screen comes.

But It shows loading ProgressIndicator then it never goes to the second screen and expects function fails

So what should I do or what is similar to waitFor but for Flutter integration_test library?

My testing code

```
      await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key('loginButton')));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      await tester.ensureVisible(find.byKey(const Key('loadingWidget')));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      await tester.ensureVisible(find.byType(DetailsScreen));
      expect(find.text('Log In'), findsNothing);
```

Here is the login button onTap

```
BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context).add(
  LoginEvent.loginWithEmail(
    email: emailController.text,
    password: passwordController.text,
  ),
);
```

Comment: You can try to call `Future.delayed()` for set needed delay time.

Comment: I tried it but it stops the animation

Answer (score 1):

You should use [pumpAndSettle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pumpAndSettle.html) method of WidgetTester to wait until animations end. Your code will be like this:

```
  testWidgets("Login test", (tester) async {
    ...
    await tester.tap(find.byKey(ValueKey('Login')));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    ...
  }
```

Comment: I am not waiting for animation only, I wait for progress indicator and login api call so pumpAndSettle is enough for my case.

Comment: Usualy progress indicators are animating too. So pumpAndSettle() will wait for it.
As for api call - does response waiting time matches with progress indicator animation time? pumpAndSettle() should suit for you if it does.

Comment: @amorenew Anyway would you add your api call code and test code to your question?

Comment: @ Mol0ko I updated my answer with the code

Comment: I see your code, thanks. Where exactly you starts loading animation?

Comment: after tapping on the login button

Answer (score 0):

My goal is integration test so I replaced integration_test with the default Flutter driver and I was able to waitFor while animation by using

```
await driver.runUnsynchronized(() async {
//wait for something
});
```

More info: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36244

And I mock my Dio HTTP client by the following library
**http_mock_adapter**